Using Einstein Summation Convention
I am having a problem writing an expression in index notation.
With $R_I^*$ being a constant
$$ R_I^k = R_I^* W_I^k $$
my formula is
$$ N_I^g = \frac{\sum_k N_I^k R_I^k}{\sum_k R_I^k} $$
For instance, I cannot do
$$ N_I^g = \frac{N_I^k R_I^* W_I^k}{R_I^* W_I^k} $$

Not every expression can and needs to be written in index notation. Writing the two summation signs should be affordable.

Have always thought that the index notation can always be used.

The problem is how to do multiplication with a constant, yet still perform a summation.

Yes.  But haw can one do the denominator $ \sum_k R_I^* W_I^k $ with index notation ?

You cannot use the Einstein summation convention when you sum over a single index, or more than two indices at the same time. To write $\sum_kR^k_I$ in index notation you would have to introduce a dummy vector $Q^k$ that has ones in every component and write it as $Q^kR^k_I,.$ How weird.

Einstein notation is normally used for tensors and tensor operations. Summing over the indices of a vector or 1-tensor is normally not a valid tensor operation because it’s not independent of the basis of the vector space.

In that case it would be $ Q^k R_I^* W_I^k $ to describe  $ \sum R_I^* W_I^k $, right ?

If you want to confuse your readers go ahead with this. There should be more important things to do than to revolutionize a standard notation. That denominator in the expression for $N^g_I$ looks to me like a partition function from statistical thermodynamics. Nothing that calls for a summation convention.

What I can do is define the denominator as an invariant constant $C$ such that $C = \sum_k R_I^* W_I^k$.  I would agree with you that the use of the index notation does confuse. It confused me as well.

Good idea. And if you absolutely want to kill the summation sign you could write the numerator as the dot product between $N_I$ and $R_I,.$
